# confused about javascript local variable VS global variable

Tags: javascript, global-variables

Here is the code below:

```js
var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;

function Multiplication (num1,num2) {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =  num1*num2;

}
    
function Divide (num1,num2) {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =  num1/num2;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" value="2" id="num1"/>
  <input type="number" value="3" id="num2" />
  <input type="button" value="Multiplication" onClick="Multiplication()"/>
  <input type="button" value="Divide" onClick="Divide()"/>
</form>

<div>
  <span>The result is:</span>
  <p id="result"></p>
</div>
```

I am getting result NAN when i click the multiplication or divide button to trigger the function,but i thought num1 and num2 both are global variable,could someone help me figure out why the both undefined?

Comment: You aren't calling the function with any arguments, so it ends up being `undefined * undefined` in `Multiplication`, which is `NaN`. Attach a click handler to the button, and pass in the values.

Comment: its still not working even if i passed num1,num2 to the multiplication() as two arguments

Comment: Function parameters introduce local variables. Given that you didn't pass any values to the calls, they're set to `undefined`.

Comment: @allen.w Did you pass in the variables in a click handler, or as you have in the original code? Don't embed calls to Javascript functions in HTML; it's very bad practice practice. I other words, don't use the `onclick` property of the HTML tag. Attach a click handler to the button element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are two major problems (and one minor) with your code:

First of all, your functions `Multiplication` and `Divide` have two arguments `num1` and `num2` that *shadow* the global ones, but you're calling the functions with no arguments, so inside the functions, these will have the value `undefined`. Multiplying or dividing `undefined` by itself gives NaN (*not a number*).

Secondly, even if you remove the arguments from your functions, `num1` and `num2` are the values of the two fields *when the code is running*, that is, when the page is loading. So if you change the value in the input fields, pressing the buttons would not give a different result.

Third, your variables `num1` and `num2` are *strings*, not numbers, since `.value` of an input field gives a string. This won't make a difference when you're multiplying or dividing strings, but if you're *adding* two strings, then `'1' + '1' == '11'` instead of 2, so you should use `Number()` to convert your strings into numbers.

Taking these things into account, you'd end up with something like this:

```js
function Multiplication () {    
  var num1 = Number(document.getElementById('num1').value);
  var num2 = Number(document.getElementById('num2').value);

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =  num1*num2;
}
    
function Divide () {
  var num1 = Number(document.getElementById('num1').value);
  var num2 = Number(document.getElementById('num2').value);

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =  num1/num2;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" value="2" id="num1"/>
  <input type="number" value="3" id="num2" />
  <input type="button" value="Multiplication" onClick="Multiplication()"/>
  <input type="button" value="Divide" onClick="Divide()"/>
</form>

<div>
  <span>The result is:</span>
  <p id="result"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect explanation!Thanks so much,now i completed understand where am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The way you set up your functions,

```
function Multiplication (num1,num2){...}
```

this functions is expecting two values to be given when the function is called, currently the button that calls the function doesn't pass any variables.

```
onClick="Multiplication()
```

To remedy this you would either have to remove the values when the function is defined like this,

```
function Multiplication (){...}
```

Thus instead of looking for the variables from the button that called it, it would then look for them inside the script.
If that doesn't work then change your javascript to something like this,

```
var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;


function Multiplication () {
   var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
   var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =  num1*num2;

}

function Divide () {
   var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
   var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =  num1/num2;
}
```

This should work, if you have any other questions don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Alrighty, if you need anything else, don't hesitate to ask!

Answer (score 0):

In your onclick event there is no arguments passed to these two functions.

Remove arguments and try getting num1 and num2 from within the functions you declared.

Comment: its still not working even if i passed num1,num2 to the multiplication() as two arguments.

Comment: The thing is if i move "var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;" inside of multiplication function then it is working as expected,that is what i am getting confused about.

Answer (score 0):

Global and local variables concept is same almost in all languages.

```
//global variables
var num1=parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value);
var num2=parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value);

function Multiplication () {
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =  num1*num2;
}

function Divide () {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =  num1/num2;
}

//local variables
function Multiplication () {
    var num1=parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value);
    var num2=parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML= num1*num2;
}

function Divide () {
    var num1=parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value);
    var num2=parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value);
     document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=num1/num2;
}
```